# Word for the nuances that only an expert might see

Tags: vocabulary

For example, two techniques might appear very similar to a casual viewer - maybe because their names sound similar - but if one understands their detail, they are very different.

I'm sure there is a word to describe the differences, nuances, intricacies that only an expert might know... but I can't remember it.

Any ideas?

Comment: [***Minutiae***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minutia) - which the *expert* might think are important, but laymen are either unaware of them, or dismiss them as "unimportant details".

Comment: Minutiae suggests that the differences are small or insignificant. But the word I am looking for is the opposite. It describes the differences that are very important, but not visible to the untrained eye.

Comment: This suggestion would only apply where the differences result from slight/hidden flaws/imperfections in one of the objects being examined, but expert eyes are trained to catch [catches](http://i.word.com/idictionary/catch).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use [***subtleties***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/subtleties?showCookiePolicy=true), [***fine points***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/finest) or [***refinements***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/refinement)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the expression is that such things are ***invisible*** to the untrained eye.

> **To the untrained eye**
>
> - to someone without the skill or knowledge to judge what they see: *To the untrained eye, most fake diamonds look real.*
>
> <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/untrained)</sub>

Comment: They're looking for the opposite of that.

Comment: @PixelSnader - You're wrong, I'm afraid. Have a read through OP's question again.

Comment: I don't mean in the sense of trained vs untrained. I mean in the sense of that description being negative (a NON expert would NOT notice) which means there could be a better way. (although I've been breaking my head on it with no result). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @PixelSnader - Read my answer again: I wrote ***invisible** to the untrained eye*: i.e. a non-expert would NOT notice.

Comment: Yes, and that's a double negative. What I mean is they're asking for (analogy) a word that means "good", and you suggest "not bad".

Comment: They're not asking  for a word that means "good", @PixelSnader. This is a very good answer.

Comment: @PixelSnader - I now see what you mean: you are saying that the OP is looking for a single positive term which conveys this meaning, rather than a compound term composed of a double negative. I take your point, and I will try to find such a term, although I think that this answer is still valid; it meets the OP's requirements.

Comment: @Charon It's a good solution, perhaps the best one currently existing, but I can't help but think there must still be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

@fumble fingers, why didn't you post that as an answer? It is perfect. my 2nd choice would have been to refer to these as subtleties, but @SamuelVimes (what a wonderful literary reference) already claimed this answer. This leaves a couple of alternates:

> **[Aspect](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aspect#aspect__2)** - A particular part or feature of something, A specific way in which something can be considered, A particular appearance or quality.
>
> **[Facet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/facet#facet__6)** - A particular aspect or feature of something